# Prolog '==' operator is not working?

Tags: prolog

I made a function which calculates vector length and 2D array size.

Below is the function. I am using **swi-prolog**:

```
foo(LIST) :- listLength(LIST, COUNT1), twoDarray(COUNT2), 
write("vector len : "), write(COUNT1), 
write(",  2D array size : "), write(COUNT2).
```

Yes, I deliberately exclude detailed `listLength, twoDarray`function.

However two functions are correct. So, `COUNT1` variable stores vector length and `COUNT2` variable stores 2D array size.

Also input variable `LIST` means vector. 2-dimension table is fixed.(7 by 7).

When I run the code with the input:

> ?- foo([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).

it outputs:

> vector len : 5,  2D array size : 49

[image: result(1)]

But, when I modified above code like below,

```
foo(LIST) :- listLength(LIST, COUNT1), twoDarray(COUNT2), 
(COUNT1 == COUNT2).
```

function is not terminated. My goal is compare `COUNT1` and `COUNT2`. If two variables are the same, then `true` is returned otherwise `false` is returned.

However, it is not working even with the same input.

[image: result(2)]

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Prolog interpreter backtracks when a goal fails, it retries `twoDarray/1` in case it may return another value for COUNT2. By default Prolog relations have multiple answers. You have to tell Prolog machine that a particular relation is a function, that is it admits only one answer.

To tell that a relation is functional you can use the *cut* operator. If you do not want to change the definitions of `twoDarray/1` and `listLength/2` you can introduce cut directly into your definition of `foo/1`. The cut operator is denoted by the exclamation mark character.

```
foo(LIST) :- listLength(LIST, COUNT1), twoDarray(COUNT2),!, 
(COUNT1 == COUNT2).
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
listLength(_, 5).
twoDarray(49).

foo(LIST) :-
  listLength(LIST, COUNT1),
  twoDarray(COUNT2),
  (COUNT1 == COUNT2).
```

work (return immediately error) with my gprolog and with my swi-prolog.

So, I suppose, the problem is in your `listLength/2` or in your `twoDarray/1`.

Suggestion: substitute your `listLength/2` with my fake one and try again.

Next try with my fake `twoDarray/1`.